# Neutralize HTTP headers in Yii

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii and I want to know how I can neutralize the HTTP headers of each request to not allow unexpected characters to avoid injection of malicious codes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure qhat the question is about? Yii does not inject malicious codes...

Comment: I want to make sure if the response headers allow/execute crlf characters. Or is it escaped already by Yii?

Comment: [PHP escapes newlines in headers automatically](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-changelog).